# Logged in Twilio Flex User SID

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am new to twilio and trying to develop a plugin that shows a dashboard with some data of the agent(who is logged in). Can anyone please let me know how do I get the SID of the current user in twilio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Flex Manager](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/manager) object has a `workerClient` property which gives you access to a [`Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker` object](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html), which is the logged in worker. That worker object has a `sid` property.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
const manager = flex.Manager.getInstance();
const accountSid = manager.workerClient.accountSid;
console.log(accountSid); // ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```